# Build is successful on my local but not on vsts azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I can successfully build my project on local. When I do via VSTS then build is not successful. I get an error message that a dll cannot be found in my sub project. And it is Rapportage.Logic. The missing dll is used by Rapportage.Logic
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: open up the actual project file in a text editor and make sure you do not have any hard-coded paths that are local to your machine.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Not yet. I could not spend time on this. But I will take the steps you mentioned in your answer. I think after that it is solved. I will then update it here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this type of error comes down to:

1. files present/edited on developer machine but not commited (usually the .csproj file)
2. subtle differences between Visual Studio build and MSBuild.

I would try the following:

1. copy the MSBuild command from Azure DevOps logs (the line containing `MSBuild.exe`)
2. change the paths in the command to match your dev environment (e.g `d:\a\1\s` to `c:\code\myproject`)
3. run this command

If this command fails with the same error as the build you the problem is a difference between MSbuild and Visaul Studio.

If it succeeds, you most likely have missed a commit.

Answer (score 0):

> Build is successful on my local but not on vsts azure DevOps

It depends on how you add ReportViewer references.

If you add the ReportViewer reference manually, you need add the ReportViewer reference to the solution/project folder, then add the reference from that folder. In this case, the  path of references are not hard-coded paths. Besides, you need add those/this ReportViewer reference to the source control and submit to the Azure devops repos.

If you add the ReportViewer reference by nuget, you need add the nuget restore task to restore those nuget packages. I could see you are using nuget restore task from your build log (The second image.), but on the build definition, I did not see you have add that task (The 3rd, 4th images.). So, make sure you have restore those packages when you build on the Azure devops, and you could check the restore task if those nuget packages are restored.

Hope this helps.